# How to load static image in server/api in Nuxt3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nitro

I am trying to implement an API function in the built-in server in Nuxt (Nitro). Right now in this function I am generating a PDF using JSPdf but I can't insert images into the PDF when I deploy it to production (in Vercel). Right now when I run the app with npm run dev it works.

My code is the following:

```
  let filepath2 = path.join(process.cwd(), "assets", "images", "logo2.png");

  const data = fs
    .readFileSync(
      filepath2
    )
    .toString(encoding);

  const uri = "data:" + mime + ";" + encoding + "," + data;

  doc.addImage(uri, "png", x, y, logoWidth, logoHeight, "logo", "MEDIUM", 0);
```

This works in local with npm run dev, but when I deploy it to Vercel it shows an error telling it can't find the file.

How can I access a image in server side when I deploy it?

Comment: try logging the result of `process.cwd()` and see where you are

Comment: @GeorgiStefkoff Doing that I get that I am in " /var/task ", but I don't know how I could access the images I want.

Comment: what is your directory structure of the app?

Comment: @GeorgiStefkoff Summing up, my nuxt project would be something like this, starting from the root of the project: ___________
> components (with my components and from where I call the API) ___________
> assets / images / logo.png (here is the image I want, which I can find when running npm run dev) ___________
> server / api / generatePdf.ts (This is where I have all my code for generating the PDF)

It is kind of hard to format the comment here but I hope you can understand it.

Comment: @user23493327 see [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/52711#issuecomment-1855735947)

Comment: @GeorgiStefkoff Tried that but it did not work. I still get a similar error in Vercel logs: ________

Unhandled Promise Rejection  {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/public/logo.png'","reason":{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/public/logo.png'","code":"ENOENT","errno":-2,"syscall":"open","path":"/var/task/public/logo.png","stack": ... (and more)

Just in case, the filename is correct, I changed it to just logo.png

Comment: @KJ But it is working in local when I run that, isn't the problem coming from how I try to locate the file in Vercel?

Comment: @KJ The code I posted is in the server side. My idea is to have a frontend with a button to generate PDF, and then sends a request to the server, the server generates the PDF and then sends it back to the client.